# How to create type in typescript to force object have properties based on values of static array

Tags: typescript

I don´t know if it is possible but here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```js
type A = { flags: ['flagNameA']; propertyA1: string; propertyA2: string };
type B = { flags: ['flagNameB']; propertyB1: number };
// And more type definitions C, D, ...

type SomeType = // how to define it based on A, B, etc

const var1: SomeType = { // valid
  flags: ['flagNameA'],
  propertyA1: 'value',
  propertyA2: 'value',
};

const var2: SomeType = { // valid
  flags: ['flagNameB'],
  propertyB1: 1,
};

const var3: SomeType = { // valid
  flags: ['flagNameA', 'flagNameB'],
  propertyA1: 'value',
  propertyA2: 'value',
  propertyB1: 1,
};

const var4: SomeType = { // error because flags has value 'flagNameB' but does not define property 'propertyB1'
  flags: ['flagNameA', 'flagNameB'],
  propertyA1: 'value',
  propertyA2: 'value',
};
```

I want to define type `SomeType` based on types A, B, etc. Then if the flags array contains a value from the other types, it also forces to declare the other properties. Is this possible?

Also I want to limit the possible values that flags array can contain (so, limited number of flagNames).

Later if I write something like:

```js
if(var3.flags.includes('flagNameA')) { // get intellisense for possible flagNames
 var3.propertyA1 = 'otherValue'; // safe to assign, because flags array including flagNameA ensures propertyA1 exists
 var3.propertyB2 = 2; // not safe, because it only ensures var3 has properties for flagNameA (of type A)
}
```

I tried to use Unions and Intersections of typescript, without luck.

I expect to get an error if I don´t define the properties corresponding
to the flag names in the flags array, and get intellisense.

Comment: There's not a good scalable way to write `SomeType` as a single type, unless your list "`A`, `B`, etc" is fairly short.  You can make it generic and use a helper function instead: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqoedw) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: For now the list of types is length 4, but I expect it to increase in the future. My idea is to extend the type to create classes. Your suggestion is really interesting, could you explain it more implementing or extending the type to create a class?

Comment: "I think it doesn't meet my needs". Can you explain why? What specifically is the difference for your use case between `const x = someType({⋯})` and `const x: SomeType = {⋯}`? Can you [edit] to demonstrate with a [mre] in the question?  If it turns out that you really cannot use a generic type, then the answer to this question is "no, this is impossible for anything but very short lists of types".  I could write *that* up as an answer, but it's fairly unsatisfying.

Comment: Oh, you edited your comment. Okay, well, if you mean you need `class X implements SomeType` then that would never work no matter what, since `SomeType` doesn't have a set of properties which is known in advance.  At best it's a union type, but you can't implement unions.  It sounds like your use case would never be met by any answer to this question, meaning it feels like an XY problem.  I could imagine working around it with a whole bunch of type assertions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2gpjN), but I don't know that it's useful to you.  How shall we proceed here?

Comment: Let me investigate some days based on your suggestion and if I find something, I´ll be back to you or will write an answer.

Comment: @jcalz I investigated and tried things based on your suggestion, and then I understand it is not possible to create an interface or type that based on the values of the array in a class implementation forces you to add the properties. I understand it is the opposite. Given an object, you can then extract the type.
My original question was not formulated correctly to solve my problem. I have thought on some alternatives but I am still stuck and don't know even if it is possible. [This is what I did](https://tsplay.dev/mpoxpN). Could be possible to create a type predicate as I mention there?

Comment: Your initial suggestion solves my original question, so feel free to add an answer.

Comment: Yes you can make a type predicate as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQj0vN). What should we do here, should I go ahead with the original answer or do you want to [edit] the question to reflect the new version?

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. I would have expected not having generics (because then I have to repeat the flags twice (in the generic and the array)), but that´s fine too. Is it possible to pass multiple generics like `MyInterfaceWithFlags<'flagNameA', 'flagNameB', ...>`? Thanks. You can go ahead with your answer to the original question.

Comment: Otherwise I can write `class Implementation1 implements MyInterfaceWithFlags<'flagNameA'>, MyInterfaceWithFlags<'flagNameB'>`. Never mind.

Comment: `MyInterfaceWithFlags<'flagNameA' | 'flagNameB'>` should also work. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no scalable way to make a specific `SomeType` that works. It would need to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) that covers every possible set of flags separately. Such a union is only manageable if your list of types is very small, because number of sets of flags grows exponentially with the number of possible flags.

Instead, you can make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that takes the set of flags as a type parameter and computes the intended type, which would be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all the pieces.  It could look like this:

```
interface Mapping {
  flagNameA: { propertyA1: string; propertyA2: string };
  flagNameB: { propertyB1: number }
}

type SomeType<K extends keyof Mapping> = { flags: K[] } &
  ({ [P in K]: (x: Mapping[P]) => void } extends
    Record<K, (x: infer MK) => void> ? MK : never);
```

This uses a technique like that in [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) to convert the union of keys `K` into an intersection of mappings:

```
type ExampleA = SomeType<"flagNameA">;
/* type ExampleA = {
    flags: "flagNameA"[];
} & {
    propertyA1: string;
    propertyA2: string;
} */

type ExampleB = SomeType<"flagNameB">;
/* type ExampleB = {
    flags: "flagNameB"[];
} & {
    propertyB1: number;
} */

type ExampleAB = SomeType<"flagNameA" | "flagNameB">;
/* type ExampleAB = {
    flags: ("flagNameA" | "flagNameB")[];
} & {
    propertyA1: string;
    propertyA2: string;
} & {
    propertyB1: number;
} */
```

Because `SomeType` is generic, you'd need to write

```
const var1: SomeType<"flagNameA"> = { 
  flags: ['flagNameA'],
  propertyA1: 'value',
  propertyA2: 'value',
};
```

which is tedious and redundant. To avoid needing to write out the type argument, you can make a generic helper function to infer it for you:

```
const someType =
  <K extends keyof Mapping>(st: SomeType<K>) => st;

const var1 = someType({ // valid
  flags: ['flagNameA'],
  propertyA1: 'value',
  propertyA2: 'value',
})

const var2 = someType({ // valid
  flags: ['flagNameB'],
  propertyB1: 1,
});

const var3 = someType({ // valid
  flags: ['flagNameA', 'flagNameB'],
  propertyA1: 'value',
  propertyA2: 'value',
  propertyB1: 1,
});

const var4 = someType({ // error, Property 'propertyB1' is missing
  flags: ['flagNameA', 'flagNameB'],
  propertyA1: 'value',
  propertyA2: 'value',
});
```

This works how you'd like.  Yes, it's not in exactly the same form, but `const v: SomeType = {⋯}` and `const v = someType({⋯})` are similar in terms of amount of information and keystrokes, and the latter has the advantage of actually working.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFkEAcvgOaoDewqqcANgngHIIC2UAggFxGpYwD2WsEAnowCMrAM4QY+ANzsuPGP0YAmUePyoAvpJJlKNelABCrQjO68+B4ajABXOgCNYG4OuDB+PVAGVODACp8PAA8ANKoUAAe0GAAJiKoANZQfJxwGNi4YHgAfKgAvGwUVCKsIQDaALoaqABk2gAUJmUACqjgqCEVrPURrJg4+C0VAJT5uQBunCAx1ZHRcdqkAEpQSJwwMaEANKg9rOBwTugho3kTUzG5APwYYaxgUOOww1rugWgAohH0WORM+d5fFAAsEAERFPQMRig7JaAD0ACpUB5Pt86L9-gViKRSBCSqhwbpaFDQZUtOpakRFqY5AorGIJFktDiaeYlCpGXhyagEXC3CjUF8fn8DACfP53kFCVRiYYYfCkQKheiRQDsTi8axpZC5WSXJT1aQOGZ5BYrLYHLBubz+e9BWiMYxRQVxcDJdrZdDUAAfAkQ2UGeXARHIu3Kx3OqkszW7D36L2+uMMQPDPUUmpRnHG2kCemqJnU7Ns5SoBlSfUZw2s02We52Rwwa184BrMBiUtAkFoPLaULhKJQWLxJIpNL9TI5epiViuruhbKnXJiV6t9vjBAwQQAkSd96NVBwuGodfkabaGNlADk-vjl4qW20RdNQlYl5PNigl4fRtkxdf78-B91GGNxVwgY8N0Ubddx4fdDwg08YnPXR8SvG9kzvb9q34WtUEEICXlAzg23A9cYAAZmgiVYJMeCTzPXEUNYNCiVvHZr1YjD70fX9nysN8EHID8vx4k0FBLAShMA0Sc1w-CXEIltiLXDcABYqLdGiDyPWAuBgHZml4-hUEvJ8cMES82niOgQBEER8GQ4pmI4mU2JM9DDEwmS2X4gCRJ-MSBAkvyCMkIA)